# responsible person, person in charge or designated person?

Tags: business-language

I am looking for a term that is commonly used in business reports to indicate the responsible person or person in charge of certain activities(for example, person who performed product inspection to be reported in a inspection document)

I am not sure which of the following terms is more appropriate and if these terms are actually used in business reports.

*Responsible person/Person in charge/Designated person*

Comment: How about ***inspector***?

Comment: _superintendent_, maybe.

Comment: *manager, supervisor, director, head, controller, administrator,...*

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments!